# Creating a new document on SharePoint 2013 with Office 2016 installed opens Office web app first

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem, office-web-apps, office-integration

I'm testing my organisations new Windows 10 PC build with Office 2016 installed (we currently use W7 with O2010).

When a new document is created in our on premise SharePoint 2013, I'm first prompted to enter the document name and properties. After this the document opens in the Office Web App. I have to click 'Open in < application name >' to use the client app. This is true for Word, Excel and PowerPoint. How can this be stopped from happening?

All libraries are configured to open documents in the client application by default.
When existing documents are opened, they open in the client application as expected.